# How to satisfy the condition of 2 columns different rows at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My logic is like this:

`cond2` column is true before `expected` column, and `cond1` column is true before `cond2` column, then `expected` column can be true

input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d={'cond1':[False,False,True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False],'cond2':[False,True,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

expected result table

```
    cond1   cond2   expected
0   FALSE   FALSE   
1   FALSE   TRUE    
2   TRUE    FALSE   
3   FALSE   TRUE    
4   FALSE   TRUE    
5   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
6   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
7   TRUE    FALSE   
8   FALSE   TRUE    
9   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
```

I have such an idea

get the number of lines from `cond1` is true to the present, and then use the cumsum function to calculate the number of lines where `cond2` is true is greater than 0

But how to get the number of lines from `cond1` is true to the present

Comment: It's unclear, do you mean n-1 col 2 is True and n-2 col1 is True? This doesn't seem to be the case for row 5

Comment: If you had False for cond2 at index 8, should you not have True at index 9?

Comment: yes,it's not have True at index 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is not fully clear. It looks like you need a `cummax` per group starting with True in cond1:

```
m = df.groupby(df['cond1'].cumsum())['cond2'].cummax()

df['expected'] = df['cond2'].ne(m)
```

Output:

```
   cond1  cond2  expected
0  False  False     False
1  False   True     False
2   True  False     False
3  False   True     False
4  False   True     False
5  False  False      True
6  False  False      True
7   True  False     False
8  False   True     False
9  False  False      True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're looking for~

```
df['expected'] = ((df.index > df.idxmax().max())
                  & ~df.any(axis=1))

# Output:

   cond1  cond2  expected
0  False  False     False
1  False   True     False
2   True  False     False
3  False   True     False
4  False   True     False
5  False  False      True
6  False  False      True
7   True  False     False
8  False   True     False
9  False  False      True
```